# How to run AVD Manager on Mac

Tags: android, macos, bash

I tried command line in tools directory within terminal by typing android and

and bash says it cannot find the command. When I type ls I can see android.

Also am I obliged to use command line. Why Eclipse does only show a button for running SDK Manager which is not used often instead of AVD Manager ?

Comment: What SDK version are you using? SDK and AVD Manager in Eclipse has been splited into two separate bottons since recent release.

Comment: For the command line: If you want to start a program/tool/script in a directory, which is not in the PATH (echo $PATH), then type ./<program>. In your case ./android

Comment: "android avd" will launch just the device manager.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Eclipse -> Windows -> AVD Manager, You can make note of the button.

Eclipse shows both buttons (SDK and AVD Manager)

Am using -Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.0

Answer (score 84):

If you don't want to use Eclipse this will fire it up.

Under tools folder write the following:

./android avd

Comment: I agree. It helped me too.

Comment: deprecated at the moment.

Comment: Invalid or unsupported command "avd"

Answer (score 28):

Today Eclipse has been replaced with Android Studio in the SDK bundle.

Android Studio for Mac installs the SDK in a subfolder in the user's Library folder, so the full command line to launch the AVD becomes:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd
```

Comment: 5 years later even this isn't a thing anymore. `avdmanager` has its own command

Answer (score 21):

On newer versions of Android Studio, this should be done by running the `avdmanager` binary located on `tools/bin/` (relative to the *SDK* root directory):

```
$ ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager
```

The same applies to the *SDK Manager*:

```
$ ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager
```

Comment: `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager` does not run the GUI app. How to open GUI AVD Manager?

Answer (score 19):

**avdmanager** used **only for create/move/remove** avds.
GUI can be used only in Android Studio (I think GUI is a part of Idea plugin, not an independent app like before in Eclipse)

For run emulator from console use this:

For list available AVDs:

`~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -list-avds`

For run emulator:

`~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator @AVD_NAME`
`@` - required