# Mac Terminal - How to start Android Virtual Device Manager on CLI?

Tags: command-line, terminal, command-line-interface, osx-snow-leopard, android-virtual-device

I am currently developing a mobile web application and I don't have a test device yet so I'm using the [android-emulator](/questions/tagged/android-emulator) to check the site. On my mac, I have installed the stand-alone Android SDK. Every time I want to use the AVD Manager, I have to execute the following on my terminal:

```
monitor
```

This command (being executed on the installed android sdk path) will open the Android Device Monitor and from here, I go to its menu bar and select **Window Virtual Device Manager** just to open the AVD Manager. So, is there a shortcut for that? I mean, i want to directly open the AVD manager via [cli](/questions/tagged/cli).

Comment: Ubuntu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202353/tell-me-the-command-line-to-open-avd-manager-on-linux-ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run AVD Manager on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940732/how-to-run-avd-manager-on-mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Android SDK Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager.html):

```
avdmanager
```

Or you can also start it by using the command below but it's **deprecated** though on newer version. Before executing it, make sure to export your Android SDK's tools directory in your `~/.bash_profile` (i.e. `export PATH="/Users/user/Software/android-sdk-macosx/tools:$PATH"`)

```
android avd
```

#### Old answer:

In order to open the [avd](/questions/tagged/avd) manager on terminal, execute the following:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xmx256M -XstartOnFirstThread \
 -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=/path/of/android-sdk-macosx/tools \
 -classpath /path/of/android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/sdkmanager.jar:/path/of/android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/swtmenubar.jar:/path/of/android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/x86_64/swt.jar \
 com.android.sdkmanager.Main avd
```

Comment: use `avdmanager` or `sdkmanager`: >The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

Answer (score 59):

I was able to open it from terminal with:

```
android avd
```

You may need to navigate to your SDK tools/ first. Here is reference I used:
[AVD Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/avd-manager.html)

Comment: The `android` command is deprecated https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html says: "This tool is no longer supported. You should instead use Android Studio to create AVDs and create projects."

Comment: use `avdmanager` or `sdkmanager`: >The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

Answer (score 21):

Go to tools directory inside your android sdk like:

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools
```

and enter run your avd as

```
./emulator -avd <your-avd>
```

You can find your avd name by running:

```
./emulator -list-avds
```

Comment: Between all solution this worked for me on MacOS @ Sept 2017.

Answer (score 5):

You can start emulator use terminal shell

```
emulator -avd <avd_name> [<options>]
```

options can be special -http-proxy, -dns-server setting. Get more options [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html)

And to list all avd you can use:

```
emulator -list-avds
```

result like following:

```
4.7_WXGA_API_23
Nexus_5X_Edited_API_23
```

Example when I start Nexus_5X_Edited_API_23 emulator in OS X 10.11 with proxy setting

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_Edited_API_23 -http-proxy http://username:password@local_server:8080
```

Answer (score 3):

this is just a small addon to previous solutions presented. What is probably handy to do is to just jam this as a alias into your bash_profile like so:

Open your bash_profile:

> nano ~/.bash_profile

Add this:

> alias avd='cd /path-to-sdk/tools; ./android avd'

Source it again:

> source ~/.bash_profile

In the CLI type:

> avd

Now you can open up the AVD by just using avd in the command line. The only thing i haven't figured out how to make it stay alive after closing the terminal. Maybe somebody has tips on that.

Comment: To avoid running it from the terminal (and hence having a terminal window), create a script file in the tools folder, say avd.sh, make it executable, with the contents "./android avd" (without the quotes of course). Only useful if running from a file browser or your menu though.

Comment: To run from the terminal then close the terminal, use "nohup ./android avd"

Comment: use `avdmanager` or `sdkmanager`: >The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

Answer (score 0):

```
emulator -avd  <nameOfYourAvdEmulator>
```

Find the names of your emulators using `avdmanager list avd`:

```
avdmanager list avd
    Name: Nexus_5X_API_23_Android_6.0
  Device: Nexus 5X (Google)
    Path: /Users/edward3/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_23_Android_6.0.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on: Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
    Skin: nexus_5x
  Sdcard: 512M
```

Add to your ~/.profile if missing:

```
# Add to your ~/.profile PATH to easily run emulator and avdmanager commands
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

# Create alias to run your favorite Android emulator
alias avd-run='emulator -avd  Nexus_5X_API_23_Android_6.0 &'
```

Open a new terminal or use `source ~/.profile` to reload changes made to your `~/.profile`

Start your favorite emulator using the alias you created:

```
avd-run
```