# Can't create Virtual Device on Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I'm using Mac 10.7.4. I have the latest Android Studio for Mac (0.8.14 Build 135.1538390) with the following APIs installed:

- API 16
- API 17
- API 18
- API 19
- API 20
- API 21

I have installed ALL packages from each API (System Images, SDK Platform, Samples, Sources...). I also have installed the following Tools:

[image: Tools installed]

When I try to create a Virtual Device, I get this screen, which I've never seen before:

[image]

I've tried a lot of combinations, but I always get the same result: a message saying "studio quit unexpectedly". Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you open the AVD Manager directly? It should be located in the SDK directory.

Comment: You can also try to update your Android Studio by looking at the Canary Channel, the latest version in the Canary Channel is 0.9.3.

Comment: Yay, @Blacklight's answer solved it! If you add your comment as an answer I'll mark it as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to not open the AVD Manager from within Android Studio. The app itself should be located in your Android SDK directory.

Comment: Solved the issue by opening the AVD Manager directly from the terminal, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21503456/2110884