# Cannot Create Virtual Device on MacOS + SDK Error

Tags: java, android, macos, sdk, android-emulator

I have been having this problem:
[Can't create Virtual Device on Android Studio on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057978/cant-create-virtual-device-on-android-studio-on-mac)

So, as advised from above link, I've tried not opening AVD manager from Android studio by doing this:
**[Mac Terminal - How to start Android Virtual Device Manager on CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238476/mac-terminal-how-to-start-android-virtual-device-manager-on-cli/19238506#19238506?newreg=dd621e1229d44e8fa1be0e6732843ffa)**

And when I enter this in the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xmx256M -XstartOnFirstThread \
 -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=/path/of/android-sdk-macosx/tools \
 -classpath /path/of/android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/sdkmanager.jar:/path/of/android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/swtmenubar.jar:/path/of/android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/x86_64/swt.jar com.android.sdkmanager.Main avd
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdkmanager.Main
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try opening Android SDK manager from ..\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools by running the Android.bat file. This should open the SDK manager. You can open the AVD from the SDK manager by
Tools->Manage AVDs