# How to open the AVD manager on Ubuntu Linux from the command line?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-virtual-device

How to open the AVD manager on Ubuntu Linux from the command line?

Answer (score -16, accepted):

**Here's the command-line usage for creating an AVD:**

*android create avd -n  -t  [- ] ...*

**Example :**
android create avd -n my_android1.5 -t 2

If the target you selected was a standard Android system image ("Type: platform"), the android tool next asks you whether you want to create a custom hardware profile.

Android 1.5 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]

Use the create avd command to create a new AVD, specifying the --skin option with a value that references either a default skin name (such as "WVGA800") or a custom skin resolution (such as 240x432). Here's an example:

***android create avd -n  -t  --skin WVGA800***

or you can refer from :-

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html

Comment: The `android` command is deprecated https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html says: "This tool is no longer supported. You should instead use Android Studio to create AVDs and create projects."

Comment: The question is asking how to open AVD manager, not how to create.

Comment: SDKmanager is a better alternative https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager

Answer (score 54):

For thoose coming here because the `android avd` command has been deprecated*, here's how to do it now:

### Using Android Studio

Open Android Studio with a valid studio project (if you don't have one, simply create one empty). After you've your project open, go to `Tools => Android => AVD Manager`. Note that **this menu does not appear if you don't have a valid Android Studio project open**.

Now you can safely close Android Studio if you only want the AVD Manager.

### From command line

If you want to use the command line you'll first need to create the virtual device using `avdmanager`, located under `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager` like so:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force --name testAVD --abi google_apis/x86_64 --package 'system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86_64'
```

After you created the device to emulate, then you need to open it with `emulator`, which is located under `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator`. The command for the previously created device should be something like:

```
emulator -avd testAVD
```

If it crashes saying something like...

```
[140022905190208]:ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib
```

Ensure you're running the `emulator` command inside the `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` folder, otherwise may not work.

If you already added a device VM you can list them all with

```
emulator -list-avds
```

Check out the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html) for more details (thanks to Jeff Xiao for this—in comments).

> * The depreaction note says:

```
The android command is no longer available.
For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
```

Comment: For me, I cannot close Android studio once I open the AVD manager, it closes too. Also, it is very slow/uncertain when AVD manager will be available in the menu since it seems to have to run a bunch of gradle commands first.

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using? In my case, under Linux, I can have the AVD manager after I close Android Studio.

Comment: I am using version 3.0 of Android Studio and I don't see Android submenu under Tools

Comment: `emulator -list-avds` lists AVDs. here's a [referece](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html) on the Android Studio doc.

Comment: Thank you @JeffXiao! I've added that command to the post too :)

Answer (score 31):

Use `android avd` to open the AVD Manager.

Comment: This has been deprecated, see https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html

Comment: ************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************

Answer (score 12):

Sadly commands `android sdk` and `android avd` stopped working so to run emulator we need to use different commands to download and build all devices and its dependencies:

1. **Download sdk-tools-linux (tar.gz) from**:

https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads

2. **Unpack tools to** : `...android-sdk/tools` (...wherever you want)
3. **Go to** : `android-sdk/tools/bin`
4. **Install needed sdk libraries**:

Execute in cmd

```
sdkmanager --update

sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29" 

sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.1" "extras;android;m2repository" "tools"

sdkmanager "system-images;android-29;google_apis_playstore;x86_64"

sdkmanager "emulator"
```

5. **Setup environment variables**

Add env to system by editing ~/.bashrc (Linux) in Windows just setup system enviroments.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=../android-sdk

export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin

alias emulator="sh $ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator"
```

Note: There is possible that You need JAVA_HOME too.

Restart computer or cmd to load environments

6. **Create device**:

Go to /bin

```
avdmanager create avd -n myDevice -k "system-images;android-29;google_apis_playstore;x86_64"
```

7. **run device:**

Got to dir and run

```
cd android-sdk/tools
emulator -avd myDevice (or sh $ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -avd myDevice)
```

**Issues:**

qemu emulator not found in /bin....

```
cd android-sdk/tools/bin
ln -s  android-sdk/emulator/ emulator
```

Comment: for me, export JAVA_HOME is also needed

Answer (score 9):

For me, **`./android avd`** worked, where **`android`** was the shell script under **`android-studio/sdk/tools`**.

Comment: Deprecated as of AS 2.3, see https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html

Answer (score 7):

`./android avd` is deprecated use `~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager --help` instead!

or if it is easier for you, move to the directory and use it like in the old version:

`cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/` 
`./avdmanager`

check new `[options]` with `--help` or `-h` before you use avdmanager

first occurence in Android Studio 2.3 !

Comment: Note that the location of avdmanager varies with your install (mine is `/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager`, for example).

Comment: how can we launch avd manager GUI program without from Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Android studio:v3.0.1

Get name:

```
/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools$ android list avd
```

Start emulator:

```
/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools$ emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_23
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all to show all devices 
run the following command from the location - ~/Android/Sdk/tools

```
/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools> ./emulator -list-avds
```

then you will see the list of devices id, in my case i got following devices

```
Nexus_5X_API_28
Nexus_9_API_28
```

Now just run following command with the device id you want to run.

```
/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools> ./emulator -avd Nexus_9_API_28
```

Answer (score 0):

I created shortcut with this command

```
 /path/to/Android/emulator/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_26
```

Where "Nexus_5X_API_26" is my virtual device I created in Android Studio (2.3.3). Correct name can be checked from ~/.android/avd/ folder, where are one subfolder (with extension .avd) and one file (with extension .ini) for each. There are qcow2 files which I think could be also run directly with qemu (have not tested yet).

Answer (score -2):

I used a sudo bash command and that worked for me:

```
sudo ./avdmanager list
```

[image: after running sudo ./avdmanager list]