# Where is AVD Manager in Android Studio on macOS?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

They've changed how it works and now I can't find where it is. According to this guide https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html#viewing it should be a simple as

> In Android Studio, select Tools > Android > AVD Manager.

But I don't see any "tools" in my Android Studio client.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can find it as highlighted in the image

[image]

Tools > Android > AVD Manager should work, though. But you have to select Android Studio before you see the correct contextual menu
    .

EDIT: Since Android Studio 3.1 the path would be Tools > AVD Manager

Comment: So you have to start a project first?

Comment: It's depreceated though, that's why I tried to use the GUI. I'm using going to make an avd for Qt.io

Comment: Deprecation doesn't mean it's not working. And using a gui instead of the terminal because a terminal command is deprecated is not a very good reason in my eyes...

Comment: I'm trying to use the GUI beacause I it's easier with no experience with android development aswell so I guess I just have to create a project then

Comment: ok, that is a better reason: here is by the way the correct way to use it on the command line http://stackoverflow.com/a/42840483/3734116

Comment: And without Android Studio?

Comment: @andreszs see the above comment

Answer (score 5):

You may not have enough packages needed for the empty project. You should have a window with I think Gradle alert with a link which you can click and you will see a window with a prompt to download missing packages. When all stuff downloads the button to run ADV should be enabled.

Comment: this solved it for me: i could find AVD manager in the search field of the preferences and even assign it a shortcut but it would neither show in the toolbar, nor under tools. 

a error msg telling me i had some gradle packages or plugins missing gave me the opportunity to install the missing pcks. after that toolbar as well as menu tools > android > avd manager popped up.
thx!

Comment: I'm happy that helped you!

Answer (score 4):

I am running Android Studio on Mac OS Mojave 10.14. I found AVD Manager icon in Tool Bar.

[image: Android Studio Toolbar image]

Answer (score 0):

Its on the right to the red "stop" button on the bar

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio version 4 for MacOS, the AVD Manager and SDK Manager are under the tools menu.  Note that the menu entries do not appear until after the project has completed loading.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[AVD Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EmG3.png)Hello,
here is where you can find AVD Manager when you first open Android Studio.
More Actions> AVD Manaager

---

Use the link to see the screenshot.
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3YPu.png)