# The android command is deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

I using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, when enter **android** in terminal return this;

```
 *************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

My **.bash_profile**;

```
export PATH=$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

and I add my **.bashrc** endline;

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

How to fix this problem, ı don't create and don't run a emulator. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The error gives alternatives to perform the tasks you would using the `android` command

Comment: I want to open android avd manager but don' t run this

Comment: It already tells you what to do in the message, doesn't it?

Comment: Why not just follow this `For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager`

Comment: ./avdmanager

Usage:
      avdmanager [global options] [action] [action options]
      Global options:
....

Comment: Don' t run just show options in terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open the AVD manager on Ubuntu Linux from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202353/how-to-open-the-avd-manager-on-ubuntu-linux-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

In UBUNTU 16.04 I use following command to access avd manager and create a virtual device

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager
```

After you created the device to emulate, then you need to open it with emulator, which is located under $ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator. The command for the previously created device should be something like:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -avd testAVD
```

Try running the emulator command inside the $ANDROID_HOME/tools folder, otherwise won't work.

If your already created a virtual device from Android Studio you can check with following command

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager list avd
```

and then run it like this

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_4_API_23
```

Hope this will make you understand.

Comment: I m fixed problem with Genymotion