# How to debug a webapp/website on a Mac, without using any real device?

Tags: android, debugging, web-applications

I am desperately looking, with my friend Google, for the best practical tool to debug on Android - I mean, for real, not with Chrome.

For iOS, Apple came with their Simulator in XCode, which is great because it's replicating the exact behavior of a real device, and you have multiple choices, very handy.

What about Android? Is there something equivalent? Android Studio has been a mess for me, is there something better to advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on which environment you're coding in. If you're coding an native app you use Android Studio and it's debugger. If you're coding in React Native you'd use Chrome or React Developer Tools (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html), and so forth (Xamarin has its debugger, and the web based options use Chrome I suppose).

AVD (Android Virtual Device) is a part of the Android Studio install and it contains emulators. You can open it without opening Android Studio, if you'd like to. See this thread on how to do it in the terminal ([Mac Terminal - How to start Android Virtual Device Manager on CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238476/mac-terminal-how-to-start-android-virtual-device-manager-on-cli)).

Answer (score 0):

For Android we have Android Virtual Device (AVD). You need to ensure [Android-Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) is installed. For details creating an AVD refer to this [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) for step by step guide.

Comment: thanks, that's what I checked already, but I thought it's really not user friendly, and the debugging wasn't so efficient. That's why I am looking for something better...