# AVD Manager GUI without Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I am running macOS catalina on my macbook pro. I would like to run the AVD manager **Graphical User interface** without running Android Studio.

I am aware that there are similar questions, like this one: [How to run AVD Manager on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940732/how-to-run-avd-manager-on-mac)

However, they are different from what I am trying to achieve here:

1. I want to run the Graphical User Interface, **not** the command line tool.
   [image: This is how the AVD manager GUI looks like]
2. I want to run it on my mac running Catalina OS, **not** Windows/Linux machines.
3. I have tried running the avd-manager in $ANDROID_HOME/sdk/tools/; (without passing any other command line **arguments**)

It gives the following exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
```

Also, If I have missed a question here on StackOverflow that answers my question **fully** and which is **up to date**, I would really appreciate it if anyone could point me there.

Comment: You should check here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718973/run-avd-emulator-without-android-studio

Comment: Thanks, but I am interested in running AVD **manager** and not any particular virtual device.